# PHP Session doesn't work in my edited script

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

Just edited php sliding jquery panel form and it doesn't work, actually registration works but login doesn't. I erased some code that doesn't matter in my problem...

Please ignore these error messages in this strange language.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');

session_start();
session_name('avaLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['avaRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
echo('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $SITE_URL .'"</script>');
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Zaloguj')
{

// Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

$err = array();
// Will hold our errors


if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
    $err[] = 'Wszystkie pola muszą być wypełnione!';

if(!count($err))
{
    $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];
    echo '';
    // Escaping all input data

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM ava_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK login

        $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('avaRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);

        }
    else $err[]='Zły login i/lub hasło!';
}

if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
// Save the error messages in the session



echo('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $SITE_URL .'"</script>');
        exit;
    }
    else if($_POST['submit']=='Zarejestruj')
    {
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Twój login musi mieć pomiędzy 3 i 32 znaki!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Twoje hasło zawiera niedozwolone znaki!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Twój e-mail jest nieprawidłowy!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO ava_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($avalink)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'support@avatar.itterek.net',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        $SITE_NAME . ' - Twoje hasło',
                        'Twoje hasło to: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='Wysłaliśmy do Ciebie e-mail z nowym hasłem!';
        }
        else $err[]='Ten login jest już w użyciu!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    echo('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $SITE_URL .'"</script>');
    exit;
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $LOGIN_URL; ?>/style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $LOGIN_URL; ?>/login_panel/css/slide.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PNG FIX for IE6 -->
    <!-- http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6 -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login_panel/js/pngfix/supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="<?php echo $LOGIN_URL; ?>/login_panel/js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <?php echo $script; ?>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <h2>REGULAMIN</h2>      
                <p class="grey">Rejestracja i/lub logowanie oznaczają akceptację <a href="<?php echo $RULES_URL; ?>">regulaminu.</a>
                Jeśli jeszcze się z nim nie zapoznałeś to zapraszamy.</p>
                <h2>DOŁĄCZ DO NAS</h2>
                <p class="grey">Rejestrując się uzyskasz dostęp do szerokiej gamy polskich komiksów avatar the last airbender!</p>
            </div>


            <?php

            if(!$_SESSION['id']):

            ?>

            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Logowanie</h1>

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Login:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Hasło:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />
                    <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Pamiętaj mnie</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zaloguj" class="bt_login" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Jeszcze nie masz konta?!</h1>       

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
                        }

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Login:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                    <label>Hasło zostanie Ci wysłane.</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zarejestruj" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php

            else:

            ?>

            <div class="left">

            <h1>Panel użytkownika</h1>

            <p>Twoja subskrypcja wygasa <?php echo '???'; ?></p>
            <a href="?logoff">Wyloguj się</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">
            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Witaj <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Gościu';?>!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Rozwiń panel':'Login | Reje';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Zwiń panel</a>          
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that here:

```
    <li>Witaj <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Gościu';?>!</li>
```

user does not appear... i tried many ways to fix it and guess what?
everything works but after redirect to other page usr doesnt exists...
CHMOD 755. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and yYassuming that queries will **NEVER** fail. You should NOT be nesting database calls. Always check return values. You should also NOT be overwriting values in the superglobals.

Answer (score 2):

As documented for [session_name()](http://php.net/session_name), you **MUST** set the session name **BEFORE** you call session_start(). You are also changing the session cookie parameters AFTER `session_start()`.

You cannot do this. session settings must be changed BEFORE you start the session.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you working on the session before you've started it may be the problem.

Comment: Look at `session_start();` at the beginning of code. EDIT: Right, after using `session_destroy()` he have to start session again.

Comment: I edited it like u said but it still doesnt work properly ._.